# MvvmCross iOS UILabel AttributedText with Language converter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I create a custom control for UILabel with custom Kern parameter.

```
 [Register("CustomLabelView"), DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public class CustomLabelView : UILabel
    {
        private float _textLetterSpacing;

        public CustomLabelView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        [Export("TextLetterSpacing"), Browsable(true)]
        public float TextLetterSpacing
        {
            get => _textLetterSpacing;
            set
            {
                _textLetterSpacing = value;
                SetNeedsDisplay();
            }
        }

        public CustomLabelView()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public override void AwakeFromNib()
        {
            // Called when loaded from xib or storyboard.
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            NSRange range = new NSRange(0, Text.Length);
            var attributes = AttributedText.GetCoreTextAttributes(0, out range);
            var attributedTitle = new NSAttributedString(Text, new CTStringAttributes() { KerningAdjustment = TextLetterSpacing, ForegroundColor = TextColor.CGColor, UnderlineStyle = attributes.UnderlineStyle });
            AttributedText = attributedTitle;
            SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }
```

I bind text to this control with `language converter`

```
set.Bind(CustomLabelView)
   .For(c => c.Text)
   .To(vm => vm.TextSource)
   .WithConversion("Language", "AgreementText");
```

and `underline` property doesn't apply for bound text. Also I tried `AttributedText` property instead of `Text`. No any changes.

My *LinkerPleaseInclude* file contains this lines

```
public void Include(UILabel label)
{
  label.Text = label.Text + "";
  label.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(label.AttributedText.ToString() + "");            
}
```

Any ideas how to sort it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put `Initialize` method into `Draw` for my CustomLabel.

Here is the solution:

```
 public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
 {
     Initialize();
     base.Draw(rect);
 }

 private void Initialize()
 {
     var attributes = AttributedText.GetCoreTextAttributes(0, out _);
     AttributedText = new NSMutableAttributedString(Text,
                new CTStringAttributes
                {
                    KerningAdjustment = TextLetterSpacing, Font = attributes.Font,
                    UnderlineStyle = attributes.UnderlineStyle
                });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `UnderlineStyle` property's value to one of the enumeration of CTUnderlineStyle and it works for me.

```
namespace CoreText
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the style of an underline ornament.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     To be added.
        public enum CTUnderlineStyle
        {
            None = 0,
            Single = 1,
            Thick = 2,
            Double = 9
        }
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
 void Initialize()
        {
            this.Text = "This is some formatted text";
            NSRange range = new NSRange(0, Text.Length);
            var attributes = AttributedText.GetCoreTextAttributes(0, out range);
            var attributedTitle = new NSAttributedString(Text, new CTStringAttributes() { KerningAdjustment = TextLetterSpacing, ForegroundColor = TextColor.CGColor, UnderlineStyle = CTUnderlineStyle.Single });
            AttributedText = attributedTitle;
            SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
```

The underline appears,is this you want?